# detect string at the end of pattern

Tags: c, regex

I want to detect a string at the end of a pattern using C regex lib.

I'm looking for a string like ".mystring" with the litteral dot.

I expect the following to work :

```
char * pattern = "[[:alnum:]!--_]+\.(mystring)";
```

But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$ end of string anchor`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

```
char * pattern = "[[:alnum:]!--_]+\.(mystring)$";
```

Also no need to of capture group here

```
char * pattern = "[[:alnum:]!--_]+\.mystring$";
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. And thank you for your comment. It allowed me to solve my problem. Since I thought the end of the pattern was the problem, I didn't check that my pattern was broken before (I had ([-\._][[:alnum:]])* instead of ([-\._[:alnum:]])* ).